# Ring structure for the motivic spectrum/complex that represents singular cohomology?

Tags: motives, motivic-homotopy, ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

As the discussion here [Is singular cohomology representable by a (Voevodsky's) motivic complex?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42693/is-singular-cohomology-representable-by-a-voevodskys-motivic-complex)
shows, the singular cohomology of (smooth) complex varieties is represented by a motivic complex (and also by a motivic spectrum). My question is: what can be proved about the ring structure for this complex/spectrum? Is it known that this a 'weak' ring spectrum? an $A_{\infty}$-spectrum? a highly structured ring spectrum? Any hints would be very welcome!

Comment: You should take a look to this article by Joshua Roy (Theorem 1.1) The Rational and Integral motivic complex. In the rational case it is represented by commutative DGA over Q (since zoo can always strictify over rationals) and the second is represented by $E_{\infty}$-differential graded $\mathbf{Z}$-algebra. $https://people.math.osu.edu/joshua.1/mdga_short.pdf

Comment: Here is an "easy" argument in the case of topological space (that you can perform in the stable motivic category). Suppose that $R$ is an $E_{\infty}$ ring spectrum and $X$ is a space, use the internal Hom $F(-.-)$ in the category of spectra, then $F(\Sigma^{\infty} X_{+}, R)$ is an $E_{\infty}$ ring spectrum, since $\Sigma^{\infty} X_{+}$ is an $E_{\infty}$ coalgebra.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Singular cohomology is represented by an $E_\infty$ motivic ring spectrum. That spectrum is $\mathbf{R}f(H\mathbb{Z})$ where $f$ is right adjoint to the stable topological realization functor and $H\mathbb{Z}$ is the topological Eilenberg-Mac Lane spectrum. Since this is a symmetric monoidal Quillen adjunction (see Theorem A.45 here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.3905.pdf), $\mathbf{R}f$ preserves $E_\infty$-objects.

The same argument should show that the motivic complex is also $E_\infty$, but I don't know a reference for the required symmetric monoidal adjunction. At least if you work with $(\infty,1)$-categories this adjunction comes for free from the fact that motivic complexes are the same thing as modules over the motivic Eilenberg-Mac Lane spectrum, whose topological realization is $H\mathbb{Z}$.